Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.views.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class .viewmodels.AuthViewModel
I am getting following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lexcru.lexcruapp/com.lexcru.lexcruapp.views.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lexcru.lexcruapp.viewmodels.AuthViewModel
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4006)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2462)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8377)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.lexcru.lexcruapp.viewmodels.AuthViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:309)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:299)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:273)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl_androidKt.createViewModel(ViewModelProviderImpl.android.kt:34)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:65)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:109)
at com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseActivity.createViewModel(BaseActivity.kt:75)
at com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:53)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8397)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8370)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3837)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4006) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2462) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8377) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.lexcru.lexcruapp.viewmodels.AuthViewModel. [class android.app.Application]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2485)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:307)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:299) 
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:273) 
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158) 
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl_androidKt.createViewModel(ViewModelProviderImpl.android.kt:34) 
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:65) 
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47) 
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91) 
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:109) 
at com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseActivity.createViewModel(BaseActivity.kt:75) 
at com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:53) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8397) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8370) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1403) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3837) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4006) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:111) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2462) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8377) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
Base Activity:
package com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider


import com.kbeanie.multipicker.api.entity.ChosenImage
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.R
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.APP_UI_MODE_AUTO
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.APP_UI_MODE_DAY
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.APP_UI_MODE_NIGHT
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.PreferenceHelper
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.PreferenceHelper.customPrefs
import java.util.Calendar
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

abstract class BaseActivity<V:BaseViewModel>:AppCompatActivity() {
    abstract val modelClass: KClass<V>
    abstract fun getLayout():Int
    lateinit var viewModel: V
    lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences
    private var progressDialog: Dialog? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        prefs = customPrefs()
        PreferenceHelper.init(this)
        setContentView(getLayout())
        createViewModel(savedInstanceState)
        getDataFromIntent()
        init()
        setListeners()
        addObserver()

    }
    open fun addObserver(){}
    open fun removeObserver(){}
    protected abstract fun init()
    protected open fun getDataFromIntent(){}
    protected abstract fun setListeners()
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        viewModel.writeTo(outState)
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        removeObserver()
    }
    private fun createViewModel(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[modelClass.java]
       viewModel.readFrom(savedInstanceState)
    }
    fun replaceFragment(
        fragmentContainerID: Int,
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
        fragmentToReplace: Fragment?,
        commitAllowingStateLoss: Boolean,
        argument: Bundle? = null
    ):Boolean{
        if(fragmentToReplace == null || fragmentManager == null){
            return false
        }
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        argument?.let {
            fragmentToReplace.arguments = argument
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(
            fragmentContainerID,
            fragmentToReplace,
            fragmentToReplace.javaClass.simpleName
        )
        if(!commitAllowingStateLoss){
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }else{
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
        return true
    }
    open fun showDatePicker(cal: Calendar, dateSetListener: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) {
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this@BaseActivity, dateSetListener,
            // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.show()
        datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    fun manageAppUIMode(appUIMode: Int,context: Context){
        when(appUIMode){
            APP_UI_MODE_DAY -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            APP_UI_MODE_NIGHT -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
            APP_UI_MODE_AUTO -> {
                val nightModeFlags: Int = context.resources.configuration.uiMode and
                        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
                when (nightModeFlags) {
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {

        return viewModel.checkPermissions(
            this, arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
        )
    }
    fun applyLocationPermission(callback: (isGranted: Boolean) -> Unit) {
        viewModel.requestPermission(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            )
        ) { isGranted ->

            callback(isGranted)
        }
    }
    open fun hideKeyboard() {
        val imm: InputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
        var view: View? = currentFocus
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = View(this)
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0)
    }
    fun showProgressDialog(
        mContext: Context,
        title: String = ""
    ) {
        // Check if the activity is finishing
        if (!isFinishing) {
            progressDialog = Dialog(this)
            progressDialog!!.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            progressDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_progress)

            /* Custom setting to change TextView text,Color and Text Size according to your Preference*/
            val progressTv = progressDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.progress_tv) as TextView
            progressTv.text = resources.getString(R.string.loading)
            progressTv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white))
            progressTv.textSize = 19F

            progressDialog!!.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
            progressDialog?.let {
                if (it.isShowing) {
                    it.dismiss()
                } else {
                    it.show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun hideProgressDialog() {
        progressDialog?.let {
            it.dismiss()
            it.cancel()
        }
    }

    fun hideStatusBar(){
        /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )*/
    }
}


Base View Model:
package com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base

import android.app.Application
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.PreferenceHelper
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.nullSafe

open class BaseViewModel(application: Application): RuntimePermissionViewModel(application) {
    private val TAG = BaseViewModel::class.java.simpleName

    fun generateFcmToken() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
            .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "FCM token retrieval failed: ${task.exception?.localizedMessage}")
                    return@OnCompleteListener
                }

                // Retrieve the new FCM token
                val token = task.result
                PreferenceHelper.saveFCMToken(token.nullSafe())
            })
    }

}


Auth Repo
package com.lexcru.lexcruapp.dimodule.repositories

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.R
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.dashboard.ConditionResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.login.LoginResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.login.ProfileResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.maintenance.MaintenanceResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.otp.OTPResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.otp.ResendOtpResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.signup.BrandResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.signup.PincodeResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.models.signup.SignupResponse
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.network.Resource
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.network.RetroService
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.network.RetrofitInstance
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Response

class AuthRepository(mContext: Context) {

    val authClient: RetroService by lazy {
        RetrofitInstance.createService(RetroService::class.java)
    }

    val pincodeClient: RetroService by lazy {
        RetrofitInstance.createPincodeService(RetroService::class.java)
    }

    var mContext = mContext



    fun isMaintenanceOn(user_id: String,page: String): MutableLiveData<Any> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Any>()
        var maps = HashMap<String,String>()
        maps.put("pagename",page)
        val authClientCall =
            authClient.callMaintenanceDashAPI(maps)
        data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(true)

        authClientCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<MaintenanceResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<MaintenanceResponse>,
                response: Response<MaintenanceResponse>
            ) {

                //JLog.e("TAG", "Loading: false")
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val mBean: MaintenanceResponse? = response.body()
                    if (mBean?.status == 200) {
                        data.value = Resource.Success(mBean)
                    } else {
                        data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mBean?.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<MaintenanceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                //JLog.e("TAG", "Loading:onFailure false")
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)
                data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mContext.getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_connection))
            }
        })
        return data
    }

    fun loginUser(params: HashMap<String,String>): MutableLiveData<Any> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Any>()
        val authClientCall =
            authClient.callOTPGenerateAPI(params)
        data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

        authClientCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                response: Response<LoginResponse>
            ) {

                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val mBean: LoginResponse? = response.body()
                    if (mBean?.status == 200) {
                        data.value = Resource.Success(mBean)
                    } else {
                        data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mBean?.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)
                data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mContext.getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_connection))
            }
        })
        return data
    }

    fun verifyOTP(params: HashMap<String,String>): MutableLiveData<Any> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Any>()
        val authClientCall =
            authClient.callOTPVerificationAPI(params)
        data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(true)

        authClientCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<OTPResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<OTPResponse>,
                response: Response<OTPResponse>
            ) {

                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val mBean: OTPResponse? = response.body()
                    if (mBean?.status == 200) {
                        data.value = Resource.Success(mBean)
                    } else {
                        data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mBean?.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<OTPResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)
                data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mContext.getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_connection))
            }
        })
        return data
    }

    fun resendOTP(params: HashMap<String,String>): MutableLiveData<Any> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Any>()
        val authClientCall =
            authClient.callResendOTPAPI(params)
        data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(true)

        authClientCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<ResendOtpResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResendOtpResponse>,
                response: Response<ResendOtpResponse>
            ) {

                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val mBean: ResendOtpResponse? = response.body()
                    if (mBean?.status == 200) {
                        data.value = Resource.Success(mBean)
                    } else {
                        data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mBean?.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResendOtpResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)
                data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mContext.getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_connection))
            }
        })
        return data
    }

    fun brandList(): MutableLiveData<Any> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<Any>()
        val authClientCall =
            authClient.callBrandListAPI()
        data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(true)

        authClientCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<BrandResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<BrandResponse>,
                response: Response<BrandResponse>
            ) {

                //JLog.e("TAG", "Loading: false")
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val mBean: BrandResponse? = response.body()
                    if (mBean?.status == 200) {
                        data.value = Resource.Success(mBean)
                    } else {
                        data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mBean?.message!!)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<BrandResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                //JLog.e("TAG", "Loading:onFailure false")
                data.value = Resource.Loading<Boolean>(false)
                data.value = Resource.Error<String>(mContext.getString(R.string.lbl_no_internet_connection))
            }
        })
        return data
    }

   

}

AuthViewModel
package com.lexcru.lexcruapp.viewmodels

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.R
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseViewModel
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.dimodule.repositories.AuthRepository
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.network.Resource
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.APIConstant
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.utils.CommonUtils.checkInternetConnected
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.views.NoInternet

class AuthViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository,
) : BaseViewModel(application) {

    val mContext = application.applicationContext

    init {
        generateFcmToken()
    }
    val resendOtpStatus: MediatorLiveData<Any> by lazy {
        MediatorLiveData<Any>()
    }
 fun resendOtp(params: HashMap<String,String>) {
        when {
            !mContext.checkInternetConnected() -> {
                resendOtpStatus.value =
                    Resource.NoInternetError1<String>(R.string.default_internet_message)
                NoInternet.startActivity(mContext)
            }
            else -> {
                resendOtpStatus.addSource(
                    authRepository.resendOTP(params)
                ) {
                    resendOtpStatus.value = it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Login Activity:
package com.lexcru.lexcruapp.views

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent

import androidx.activity.viewModels

import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.R
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.base.BaseActivity
import com.lexcru.lexcruapp.viewmodels.AuthViewModel

import kotlin.reflect.KClass

class LoginActivity : BaseActivity<AuthViewModel>() {
    private val authViewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()
    override val modelClass: KClass<AuthViewModel>
        get() = AuthViewModel::class

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        hideStatusBar()
        return R.layout.activity_login
    }

    override fun init() {
    authViewModel.generateFcmToken()
        authViewModel.requestPermission(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
            )
        ) { isGranted ->

        }
    }

    override fun setListeners() {

    }
    companion object {
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

}


Use ViewModel Factory so the ViewModel Knows how to instantiate it's dependencies

Your ViewModel doesn't know how to instantiate its dependencies application and authRepository.
You either need to create a ViewModel Factory: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories
or use a dependecy injection tool, such as Hilt (Recommended): https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack

I tried with ViewModel Factory but not getting solution but need to try with Hilt dependency injection...

Why problems did you have with ViewModelFactory?
